# Nginx: redirecting multiple http servers to SSL: config not working

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to put an nginx together with the following setup:

I have two http servers running on my localhost.
One listening on port 8080, the other on port 8081.

Both should be served through https and

1. the production server listening on 8080 should be accessible
   to www.awesomesite.io.
2. the test server listening on port 8081 should be accessible through
   test.awesomesite.io.

Somehow, when navigating to the test.awesomesite.io the nginx server directs me to my production server.

I use the following configuration to direct www-requests to localhost:8080 and test-request to 8081.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.awesomesite.io;
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;    # force redirect http to https
    server_tokens off;
}

# SSL port production server
server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; 
        listen 443 ssl; 
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.awesomesite.io/fullchain.pem; 
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.awesomesite.io/privkey.pem; 
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 
    ssl on;

    server_name www.awesomesite.io;
    server_tokens off;
    # ......
    location / {
      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;

      proxy_read_timeout  1200s;
    }

}

# SSL test server

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  test.awesomesite.io;
    rewrite ^ https://$host:8443$request_uri? permanent;    # force redirect http to https
    server_tokens off;
}


server {
        listen [::]:8443 ssl ipv6only=on;
        listen 8443 ssl; 
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.awesomesite.io/fullchain.pem; 
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.awesomesite.io/privkey.pem; 
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 
    ssl on;


    server_name test.awesomesite.io;
    server_tokens off;
    # ......
    location / {
      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8081;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host:8443;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;

      proxy_read_timeout  1200s;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question in case someone had the same problem:

I used the answer of https://serverfault.com/questions/538803/nginx-reverse-ssl-proxy-with-multiple-subdomains to change my configuration.

I defined multiple server blocks with www.awesomesite.io and test.awesomesite.io name for the port 443, instead of rewriting the test subdomain to use port 8443.

After these changes, the host from the **test** request header did match the specific server block and was routed to localhost 8081.

I still did not figure out why original configuration did not work. All requests match the production server block (or at least were handle by the first server block).